# two default Constructor, one in public and one in private

Tags: c++, oop, overloading, access-specifier, constructor-overloading

My question is about constructors in OOP(C++). When I define default constructor in a class as private and when I initialize an object of that class in main as default then error occurs that default constructor is inaccessible. It's fine. But then I also make default argument constructor in Public section and when I initialize object in main again then ambiguous call to function overloading occurs. So my question is that if private constructor is not accessible from main then compiler should call the constructor in public section which is default argument constructor. Kindly answer why is this happening.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example take a class

```
#include "iostream"

class Type
{
  private:
    Type()
    {
        std::cout<<"Private Default";
    }
  public:
    Type()
    {
        std::cout<<"Public Default";   
    }
};

int main()
{
    Type obj;
}
```

Here both default constructor is in scope `Type::Type()` You can't overload like this i.e there is no private scope or public scope all are in `Type` scope So you can't overload this according to c++ overloading rules.

Output for above code:

```
main.cpp:11:5: error: ‘Type::Type()’ cannot be overloaded
     Type()
     ^~~~
main.cpp:6:5: error: with ‘Type::Type()’
     Type()
     ^~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:19:10: error: ‘Type::Type()’ is private within this context
     Type obj;
          ^~~
main.cpp:6:5: note: declared private here
     Type()
     ^~~~
```

And if you comfort with `c++11` you can delete constructor like

```
class Type
{
  public:
    Type() = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not some scope of your program is allowed to access functions and/or instantiate class types is decided by the compiler **after** overload resolution has been performed. That means available constructors are not "filtered" by their `private` or `public` visibility.

In your scenario, that might not make immediate sense when looking at the `main` function, from which you seem to instantiate objects of the class in question. But imagine you create an instance of the class from with a member function of that class: here, both `private` and `public` members are visible, and the compiler won't be able to decide which one it should take.

As a side note, if you don't want your class to be created by a default ctor, prefer to `= delete` it. Also, a default constructor and one with a defaulted single argument could certainly be refactored into two constructors, e.g. using in-class initializers.